# Eliminate email addresses from the given txt file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to eliminate  all the email addresses from a given file.

sample file mail.txt :

```
Hello from me
how are you?
shubhamg199630@gmail.com to priya@yahoo.com hi@yahoo.co.in about the meeting 
sharp @2PM.okay see you  bye@yahoo.co.in olad-hola
```

Expected output:

```
Hello from me
how are you?
 to about the meeting 
sharp @2PM.okay see you olad-hola
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub) from the `re` module, to replace the addresses with an empty string.

```
with open("mail.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

clean_text = re.sub(r"\S+@\S+", "", text)
print(clean_text)
```

This uses a simplified regular expression, which also matches invalid e-mail addresses. This removes everything, that **looks** like an e-mail address. Because you don't want to verify the correctness of the addresses, this is no problem.

Comment: How to match the email address correctness? @Wups

Comment: got it.   clean_text = re.sub(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', "", text)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) for a regular expression you can use for e-mail. Then you can use the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) from the standard library to replace all matches of that regular expression by an empty string.

Using the regular expression in the accepted answer of the question in the link we have

```py
import re

with open("sample.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()

    pattern = r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"""
    replaced_content = re.sub(pattern, "<removed>", content) 

    print()
    print(replaced_content)
```

This prints the text

```
Hello from me
how are you?
<removed> to <removed> <removed> about the meeting 
sharp @2PM.okay see you  <removed> olad-hola
```

Comment: Is there any other way of pattern searching?

Comment: You need to read the whole file and you need a way to identify which substrings are considered an "email". I'm not sure if there is another way besides using regular expressions or doing the same thing a regular expression does by hand.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
a= 'Hello from me\
    how are you?\
    shubhamg199630@gmail.com to priya@yahoo.com hi@yahoo.co.in about the meeting\
    sharp @2PM.okay see you  bye@yahoo.co.in olad-hola'

for word in a.split():
    if '@' in word:
        a = a.replace(word, '').replace('    ', '\n')

print(a)
```

Comment: It's showing error. @Erol

Comment: We can not use split as it is a string. So getting error. @Erol

Comment: @NMI, what errors are you getting?